# MS Access Multi-select Combo Box Select All/None

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a combo box on a form that is linked to a SharePoint field, the combo box populates correctly however I am having difficulty trying to add VBA code to select all of the options or to unselect all options.

With a standard combo box you can use:

```
cmbBox1.value = ""
```

and that will reset the field. The same thing can be done with a list box that has multi-select enabled however this tosses an error, "This control is read-only and cannot be modified", with the combo box that has multi-select because of the lookup.

I have done some searching however no one seems to have a real answer other than to use a listbox instead and that isn't a solution here.

Has anyone worked with one of these fields and know how to select all of the options using VBA?

Here is a link describing this type of field but it does not discuss how to interact with it using VBA - http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/use-a-list-that-stores-multiple-values-HA010031117.aspx.

UPDATE:

There has been some confusion about the type of field I was describing so I have added some screen captures to show the difference between a combo box that allows multiselect, a list box that allows multiple options and a combo box with the  option added.

First the field I was describing:

[image: MultiSelect Combo Boc]

Second the list box:

[image: Listbox with multivalue enabled]

Lastly the combobox:

[image: Combobox with a Select All option]

These images visualize the issue that was described. As you can see there are multiple check boxes that need to be selected or unselected. Normally I would not create a field like this but as described above this is how Access interprets a combobox from SharePoint that allows for multiple selections.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add functionality for ComboBox <Select All> in Microsoft Access forms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14503259/how-to-add-functionality-for-combobox-select-all-in-microsoft-access-forms)

Comment: As I explained below this is not a duplicate of the Select All. The reason is that select all option is added by changing the query that feeds the combo box to include a new option. The combo box that I descride has the functionality to select multiple items by clicking in check boxes next to each of the items. Two very different functionalities. So the prolem was how to check or uncheck all of the boxes. My answer to that is below.

Comment: Apologies, if I had realized that a single close vote was sufficient, I would not have voted.

Comment: I have added some screen captures to the question to hopefully clear up the issue for anyone else looking for this solution. You were not the first person to misunderstand so I hope this will help.

Comment: Can you Share the script of first Select options

Comment: @AbdulWaheed You want to create the multi-select with the check boxes?

Comment: Yes, Got Solution, Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a ton of searching and trial and error I figured it out.

To unselect all of the check boxes it is

```
cmbBox1.Value = Array()
```

So with this information I figured that to select items they have to be in an array. Creating an array with all of the items that are in the combo box and then setting the combo box equal to the array will select all of the items.

I used a basic loop to set each element of the array

```
Dim SelVals(), i
ReDim SelVals(0 to cmbBox1.ListCount - 1)
For i = 0 to cmbBox1.ListCount - 1
     SelVals(i) = cmbBox1.Column(1,i)
Next i
cmbBox1.Value = SelVals
```

Obviously then you aren't limited to only using the entire contents - you could assign any array and those would be the values selected.

Comment: Hi, Did you already have the <SelectAll> in your combobox? or did u add it via vba?

Comment: To create the combobox example I altered the query with a UNION to add the record. Altering the SQL could be done with VBA but you would have to use the .requery() method to update the values.

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa140084(v=office.10).aspx
I beleive this covers what you are asking

Comment: No actually. This link is talking about adding an option to the combo box's source for (ALL). What I am referring to is a combo box that has  multivalue capabilities where by you select your values using check boxes. Here is a link talking about how to create such a field - http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/use-a-list-that-stores-multiple-values-HA010031117.aspx - I already have the field because of the link to SharePoint I just need to know how in VBA to select or unselect all of the check boxes.

Comment: So...  @AxGryndr , how does the link in your comment above not answer your question?

Comment: Because the link Alan posted is simply adding an (ALL) option to the drop down. The field I have is not doing that. The options in the combo box I have are selected using check boxes next to each item. I need to select all of the check boxes or unselect all of them. The reason for this is my user may want all of the options except for 1 so with there being 60+ options it would be faster to select all and  let them unselect what they don't want.