# Ms Access Combo Box option "All"

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a report, which is based on a query - 
This query is filtered based on a combo box displaying all of my 'Clients'

How could I include an option in this combo box  - which will remove the filter and show records for ALL of the clients?
Eg, the user can either select 1 client at a time for the report, or they can select the ALL option which will display records for ALL the clients

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your question is covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16598991/ms-access-multi-select-combo-box-select-all-none)
The answer links to the following [msdn article.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa140084(v=office.10).aspx)

Comment: thank you.  I have used this to create an "all" option in my combobox - however when "all" is selected - there is no data being returned?  "Private Sub cmdClientReport_Click()
    If Not IsNull(cboReports) And cboReports <> "" Then
    DoCmd.OpenReport cboReports, acViewPreview
    Else
     MsgBox "You Must First Select a Report To Print!"
     cboReports.SetFocus
    End If
    cboReports = ""
       
End Sub"

Comment: I think you'd better ask a new question if you're having trouble with the code. But glad to be of help!