# How to get values of <optgroup> and <option> in a multiple select box to send to the server via ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I hope the picture below will give you and idea of what I'm trying to do.
[image]

So I select the categories from checkboxes. The list for each category will append in the Box A.The data retrieved from database. Next I can choose whichever item and move to box B. It will move along with the category.

Now, how do I get the categories and values for those categories inside box B, so that I can send to server to be stored in database please?

Script

```
function sendtobox(param)
            {
              xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
              if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
              if (this.responseText !== null) {
                var ajaxElm = document.getElementById('boxA');
                ajaxElm.innerHTML = this.responseText + ajaxElm.innerHTML; // append in front
                moveToBoxB(); 
               }

             }
            }

                 xmlhttp.open("GET","getsubjects.php?q="+param,true);
                 xmlhttp.send();

            }
    /*to add and remove item starts*/    
function moveToBoxB() { 
//$('#boxB').empty(); 
$.each($('#boxA > optgroup'), function() { 
var cl = $(this).attr('class'); 
if($('#boxB').children('optgroup.' + cl).length == 0) 
$(this).clone().empty().appendTo('#boxB'); 
}); 
ogVisibility(); 
/*get the value of box b items by category starts*/
//$("#boxB").children('optgroup').css({"color": "red", "border": "2px solid red"});
/*get the value of box b items by category ends*/

}

$(document).ready(function() {
$('.add').on('click', function(e) { 
e.preventDefault(); 
$.each($('#boxA option:selected'), function() { 
var og = $(this).parent().attr('class'); 
$(this).remove().appendTo('#boxB .' + og); 
}); 
ogVisibility(); 
});

$('.remove').on('click', function(e) { 
e.preventDefault(); 
$.each($('#boxB option:selected'), function() { 
var og = $(this).parent().attr('class'); 
$(this).remove().appendTo('#boxA .' + og); 
}); 
ogVisibility(); 
});
});

function ogVisibility() {
    $.each($('.show > optgroup'), function() {
        if($(this).html().trim() == "")
            $(this).css('display', 'none');
        else
            $(this).css('display', 'block');
    });

}
```

HTML

```
<ul class="small-block-grid-3 medium-block-grid-3 large-block-grid-2">
                  <li><input type="checkbox" name="level[0]" id="level" class="level" value="1"><label>Primary</label></li>
                  <li><input type="checkbox" name="level[1]" id="level" class="level" value="2"><label>Upper Secondary</label></li>
                  <li><input type="checkbox" name="level[2]" id="level" class="level" value="3"><label>University</label></li>
                  <li><input type="checkbox" name="level[3]" id="level" class="level" value="4"><label>Lower Secondary</label></li>
                  <li><input type="checkbox" name="level[4]" id="level" class="level" value="5"><label>Pre University</label></li>
                  <li><input type="checkbox" name="level[5]" id="level" class="level" value="6"><label>Skills/Languages</label></li>                 
              </ul>
```

Added submit button to trigger function

```
<section>
       <div class="row">
          <div class="small-12 medium-12 large-12 columns text-center">
              <button id="submit" onclick="sendtoserver();">Submit</button>
          </div>
      </div>

      </section>
```

But not sure what to write for this script

```
function sendtoserver()
        {
            alert($('#boxB option').prop('value'));
        }
```

Comment: did you check jquery ajax tutorial http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: @CuriousMind, yes I did just now, but I can't figure out how to get array values by category

Comment: from what you have said, you need to submit the whole select box values (not only the selected values). I dont think that is possible, you can only submit the selected values. So a solution will be to try adding/removing from databse using [ajax] on click of buttons.

Comment: @itssajan, I want to get all select box values of boxB.All selected items are here actually. I just need to know how to use jquery to get <optgroup> and it's <options> inside boxB....

Answer (score 0):

you can get the opgroup in this way

```
$('select').change(function() {
var selected = $(':selected', this);
alert(selected.parent().attr('label'));
alert(selected.closest('optgroup').attr('label'));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jkeyes/zjLCp/2/

and for the options, you can do this
$('select#my_multiselect').val() 
this will return an array of the values for the selected options - you dont need to loop through and get them yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You could:

1. Select all of the combo box ([MS Access Multi-select Combo Box Select All/None](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16598991/ms-access-multi-select-combo-box-select-all-none))
2. Post the resulting selection to the server