# Is it possible to set a default value for a combobox on Access form that is derived from a table query?

Tags: ms-access

I have a combobox with list items populated by a query.  I would like to add a default message:

"Select a Topic..."

but I can't seem to figure out if it possible.

I have tried setting the default value and this does nothing and it won't let me add an item to the list since it is bound to a query.  Just wondering if this is possible?

Thank you

Martyn

Comment: Is this a BOUND combobox (has ControlSource)? I wouldn't bother with this because if it is doable it would be complicated (have to prevent this value from actually getting accidentally saved) - and why insult user's intelligence. If you must show a message, use a label.

Comment: Okay, that is what I thought, just checking.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can change Background color for empty or not validated controls. And add ``combobox.ControlTipText = "Select value of box ..."``

Comment: Most common reason for adding a line to comboox list is to offer users an "All" option for filtering records using an UNBOUND combobox for input. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16598991/ms-access-multi-select-combo-box-select-all-none

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to do this.

Say this table:

| ID | Color |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Red |
| 2 | Green |
| 3 | Blue |
| 4 | Yellow |
| 5 | Purple |

And say we want to add "Select a Color"

If we drop in the combo box, use the wizard, then the result is this SQL. Note that OFTEN the combo box will have 2 columns, the "hidden" database PK (Primary key) column, and then the display column. You don't note in your question if you have (or want) the PK hidden value, but let's assume we do.

So, dropping in a combo box, using the wizard, the resulting SQL for the combo box is this:

```
SELECT tblcolors.ID, tblColors.Color FROM tblColors
ORDER BY tblColors.Color;
```

And thus you can change the source of the combo box to this:

```
SELECT 0 AS ID, "(Please Select a Color)" as Color FROM tblColors 
UNION 
SELECT ID, Color FROM tblColors
ORDER BY Color;
```

Note that you MUST remove the table qualifiers for the above to work.

And note how I used "()" around the text, since the "(" tends to sort (become) before actual values in the combo box.

And do be careful, as you code now has to test for the text box, or the ID value of 0.

And unlike "many" systems, Access does not automatic select the first value in the combo box, so you often require this in the form load:

```
 Private Sub Form_Load()

     Me.Combo2.Value = 0
     
 End Sub
```

The end result now looks like this:

[image]

Comment: And then maybe validation code if don't want to actually save the 0 bogus ID, if this is a BOUND control. And instead of Load code could set DefaultValue property to 0. But if relational integrity is set, won't this all fail?

Comment: It will, so, one may VERY well have to add a dummy row to the table.  We don't know if the combo box is bound, or used for some filter. Since combo's are OFTEN used for filtering and thus are un-bound, then this is not a issue. So, sure, if a combo box is to be bound, then I don't suggest adopting an "extra" selection to such combo boxes, or one will very likely have to use a un-bound combo box, and write code to setup the underlying value that eventually gets saved.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. It is a filtering combobox. Could you please clarify what you mean by Bound in this context? The combobox is bound to a table to get its list items. These items are used to add rows to a many to many join table from the form. Thank you

Comment: The term "bound control " means that the control is connected to a underlying column in the form and thus will save it's value into the record that drives the form.  So a check box can be placed on a form,  but if un bound then it don't save data.  You can have a textbox on a form,  and if un bound then it doesn't save data.  Same goes for a combo box. Unbound means it doesn't save or retrieve any data.  The fact that the list of choices is a data source for combo box it's still considered un bound.  So your combo box is still considered un bound- it's not saving data to one column in database